# Probability for union of A complimentary and B complimentary

Tags: probability

We have two ivents A and B. Don't given if they are dependent or independent, don't given if they are joint or disjoint.
$P(A) = 0.5$, $P(B) = 0.2$, $P(A \cup B) = 0.3$
Need to find $P(A^c \cup B^c)$

So, I checked for independence. $P(A)*P(B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B) => 0.1 = 0.4.$
Getting contradictory. So A and B dependent events. What should I do next and what formulas can I use to solve the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you draw a Venn diagram (or apply [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)), you'll see that
$$P(A^c\cup B^c)=1-P(A\cap B)$$

And, this intersection can be found by
$$P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B)$$

Comment: thanks for your answer. It seems correct. I also tried to get a solution like that, but was not sure is it legal to use De Morgan's law for probability theory. 
Is it legal because we are operating on sets of simple events and we can apply set theory laws here?

Comment: Of course you can. You should be able to invert events